# Replacing lines between two specific strings - sed equivalent in cmd

Tags: powershell, cmd, cygwin, text-processing

I want to replace the lines between two strings `[REPORT]` and `[TAGS]`. File looks like this

> ```
> Many lines 
> many lines
> they remain the same
>
> [REPORT]
>
> some text
> some more text412
>
> [TAGS]
>
> text that I Want
> to stay the same!!!
> ```

I used `sed` within [cygwin](/questions/tagged/cygwin):

```
sed -e '/[REPORT]/,/[TAGS]/c\[REPORT]\nmy text goes here\nAnd a new line down here\n[TAGS]' minput.txt > moutput.txt
```

which gave me this:

> ```
> Many lines 
> many lines
> they remain the same
>
> [REPORT]
> my text goes here
> And a new line down here
> [TAGS]
>
> text that I Want
> to stay the same!!!
> ```

When I do this and open the output file in Notepad, it doesn't show the new lines. I assume that this is because of formatting issue a simple `Dos2Unix` should resolve the issue.

But because of this and also mainly due to the fact that not all of my colleagues have access to `cygwin` I was wondering if there's a way to do this in [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) (or `Powershell` if there is no way to do a batch).

Eventually, I want to run this on number of files and change this section of them (between those two aforementioned words) to the text that I am providing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use PowerShell, present from Windows 7 on.

```
## Q:\Test\2018\10\30\SO_53073481.ps1
## defining variable with a here string
$Text = @"
Many lines 
many lines
they remain the same

[REPORT]

some text
some more text412

[TAGS]

text that I Want
to stay the same!!!
"@

$Text -Replace "(?sm)(?<=^\[REPORT\]`r?`n).*?(?=`r?`n\[TAGS\])",
               "`nmy text goes here`nAnd a new line down here`n"
```

The `-replace` regular expression uses nonconsuming [lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Sample output:

```
Many lines
many lines
they remain the same

[REPORT]

my text goes here
And a new line down here

[TAGS]

text that I Want
to stay the same!!!
```

---

To read text from file, replace and write back (even without storing in a var) you can use:

```
(Get-Content ".\file.txt" -Raw) -Replace "(?sm)(?<=^\[REPORT\]`r?`n).*?(?=`r?`n\[TAGS\])",
               "`nmy text goes here`nAnd a new line down here`n"|
Set-Content ".\file.txt"
```

The parentheses are neccessary to reuse the same file name in one pipe.

Comment: It's powershell, right? (I would mention it on top of the answer, just for the sake of it) Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set Inp = WScript.Stdin
Set Outp = Wscript.Stdout
Set regEx = New RegExp
regEx.Pattern = "\n"
regEx.IgnoreCase = True 
regEx.Global = True
Outp.Write regEx.Replace(Inp.ReadAll, vbcrlf)
```

To use

```
cscript //nologo "C:\Folder\Replace.vbs" < "C:\Windows\Win.ini" > "%userprofile%\Desktop\Test.txt"
```

So you can use your RegEx.

Comment: How does this replace sentences between keywords/patterns?

Comment: The same way SED does. The Global property says work on whole files. Use your **pattern**. So I could test it and make sure it works I added CRCRLF to line endings in Windows text files or converts LF to CRLF for Unix files (you did ask that as well). This is called SAMPLE CODE.